# How to use filter!() for array type in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, julia-studio

If there is the `F` array in Julia as following

```
julia> F
5-element Array{Any,1}:
  6
 28
 30
 34
 49
```

and I want to reach this

```
F
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 Any[6, 28, 30, 34, 49]
```

this code is used

```
F[1]=vcat(F[1],F[2:end])

while true
    k=2;

    if length(F)==1
        break;
    end

    filter!(x->x≠F[k],F)

end
```

It works. would you please help me? Is it possible to don't use while?
thanks very much

Comment: One way to do this is by writing `F = Any[F]`, but this is a strange thing to do. What do you want with this? Why are you turning a vector of `Int`s into a vector of `Any`? Why are you trying to put `F` inside itself? You asked a similar question recently, and then it turned out that that wasn't really what you wanted. Can you explain what your goal is?

Comment: Im coding NSGAII in Julia. I cant put all code here. `F` is pareto front set including nondominated sorted points. F[1] is the first rank of pareto front. but when F[1] is made their elements which have first rank were in F[2],....F[n] (n is length F[1]). then I had to return them to F[1] as bellow.
Because I am new in Julia. I asked here. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think you need to contort your code to put `F` inside itself. Just make a vector of vectors. You can find a discussion about something very similar here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/fast-non-dominated-sorting/24164

Comment: This link is very helpful. Thanks veryyyyy much.

Comment: Is there a reason a simple transpose wouldn't work? i.e. F = F'? or is the type needing to be `Any` the holdup...?

Comment: F is a multidimensional array (cellarray). in the first `F` included 5 elements `([]) `while I wanted` F` with one array`[]`. then transpose won't work. Thank you